# how to switch page without refresh page in django?

Tags: django

I have a menu on header and that menu has some option like :
about us, store, home, blog
I need a way to when user click on each of them, without a refresh or reload page that's template which user click show on a page ,
how can I do that?

Comment: you can achieve that with AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to call a similar AJAX function. This function replaces the text present inside `<div id="text">` with `<div id="content">` from another file. The file may be a blog, an about us or whatever you want from the same domain.

```
$.ajax({
    url: href,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#text').load(href + '#content');
    }
});
```